# StackOverflowError at Android View.setTranslationX

Tags: android

Our app crashed with the following stack trace:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.StackOverflowError
       at android.view.View.setTranslationX(View.java:10287)
       at android.view.View.setX(View.java:10237)
       at <project-package>.ui.misc.FractionalFrameLayout.setXFraction(FractionalFrameLayout.java:44)
       at android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder.nCallFloatMethod(PropertyValuesHolder.java)
       at android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder.access$400(PropertyValuesHolder.java:35)
       at android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder$FloatPropertyValuesHolder.setAnimatedValue(PropertyValuesHolder.java:962)
       at android.animation.ObjectAnimator.animateValue(ObjectAnimator.java:571)
       at android.animation.ValueAnimator.end(ValueAnimator.java:984)
       at android.animation.AnimatorSet.end(AnimatorSet.java:357)
```

We weren't able to reproduce the crash but there's one logged in crashlytics and it occurred in a Quanta device android version 4.4.2. Has anyone encountered such crash? Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT**

I checked the source code for android.view.View.java from [GrepCode](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.2_r1/android/view/View.java) but the line on 10287 is only an initialization of the class TransformationInfo.

Comment: That's a very short stack trace for a `StackOverflowError`. I guess there must be much more (including all the interesting parts).

Comment: @Henry Yes. There's actually more. Sorry. Please see updated stack trace.